# Get error when try to write value to the plist

Tags: ios, plist

I'm trying to write value to plist, but have the error

Code:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Properties" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    [dict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:Quant] forKey:@"Quant"];
    [dict writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

Error:

```
No visible @interface for 'NSDictionary' declares the selector 'setObject:forKey:'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't modify an immutable NSDictionary. You have to use a mutable copy:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path] mutableCopy];
```

Comment: No, please, don't do that... It's superfluous. `[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:]` does the job without the unnecessary copy.